# One-center two-electron integrals between 1s STO

Tags: computational-chemistry, self-consistent-field, integrals, hartree-fock, from-chem-se

As per @user1271772 's suggestion I am asking [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134515/two-electron-integrals-between-1s-sto) question here again.

---

I am trying to understand SCF cycle by trying to code up solved example from Quantum Chemistry by Levine (page 443, 5th edition). The problem is stated as:

> Do an SCF calculation for the helium-atom ground state using basis set of two 1s STOs with exponent $\zeta_1$ = 1.45 and $\zeta_2$=2.91. [Ref: Roetti and Clementi J. Chem. Phys., 60, 4725 1974]
>   $\chi_1 = 2\zeta_1^{3/2}e^{-\zeta_1 r}Y^0_0$, and  $\chi_2 = 2\zeta_2^{3/2}e^{-\zeta_2 r}Y^0_0$

One electron integrals are straight forward and I was able to get the correct answer, however I still can't get correct values for two election integral, lets say `(11|11)`. Below is my attempt in Octave

```
clear all;
N=2000;
zeta1 = 1.45;
zeta2 = 2.91;

r = linspace(0.000001,10,N)';
dr = r(2)-r(1);
chi = @(zetad,x) (2*zetad.^(3/2))*exp(-zetad*x).*x;
chichi = 0;
for i =1:N
    chichi = chichi + dr*(chi(zeta1,r(i))*chi(zeta1,r(i))*chi(zeta1,r')*(chi(zeta1,r)./((r(i)-r) + 0.000001)));
end
chichi*dr
```

However my values are way off in this case. Can anyone please shed a light on it? Value of `(11|11) = 5/8 zeta1 = 0.9062`.

Two electron integrals are defined in the Levine book as :

$$
(rs|tu) = \int \int \frac{\chi^*_r(1)\chi_s(1)\chi_t^*(2)\chi_u(2)}{r_{12}} dv_1dv_2
$$

---

user @TAR86 from the Chemistry SE suggested that

> You replaced the 6-fold integration by one in spherical coordinates. Not sure if that can work as easily as you wrote it

But I was thinking as the function have no angular dependence, at least in above case, its integral should be really straight forward.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Octave code is trying to do the integral by quadrature, which makes very little sense since it will have a huge problems with the cusp.

Since this is a one-center problem, the best approach is to use the Legendre expansion for $|r_1-r_2|^{-1}$, which decomposes the interaction into a radial part and an angular part: $r_{12}^{-1} = \frac {4\pi} {r_>} \sum_{L=0}^\infty \frac 1 {2L+1} \left( \frac {r_<} {r_>} \right)^L \sum_{M=-L}^L Y_L^M (\Omega_1) (Y_L^M (\Omega_2))^*$.

You only have $s$ orbitals; this means that the angular parts are trivial and only a single term drops out; you're left with the radial integral
$\int_0^\infty {\rm d}r r^2 \int_0^\infty {\rm d}r' {r'}^2 \chi_r(r) \chi_s(r) \chi_t(r') \chi_u(r') r_>^{-1} $
that you can solve by standard techniques i.e. dividing the integration in two parts for $r'\leq r$ and $r'>r$ and then evaluating these integrals separately.

This trick is also what makes fully numerical calculations possible on atoms, see e.g. my recent review in [Int J Quantum Chem 119, 19, e25968](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/qua.25968) ([arXiv:1902.01431](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.01431)) and the application to finite-element calculations on atoms in [Int J Quantum Chem 119, 19, e25945](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/qua.25945) ([arXiv:1810.11651](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11651))

Comment: I recommend using display mathematics whenever the formulae get as complicated as here. Invoke it with `$$ ... $$` or `\begin{align|equation} ... \end{...}` or if really necessary inline with `$\displaymath ... $`. I'd have edited it, but these are too few characters.

Answer (score 9):

This can be solved analytically, a complete solution can be found [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node128.html)

To refrain from rewriting the entire derivation I will only say that you need to integrate over all 3 dimensional degrees of freedom for both electrons, so TAR86 is correct.

In the derivation at the link, the distance between the electrons ($\mid r_1 - r_2 \mid \equiv r_{12}$) is better represented in polar coordinates (equation 1196).

Going through the algebra and calculus one can then end up with the correct solution for the Coulomb integral, -5/2 E0.

Comment: Backup in case of link-rot: https://web.archive.org/web/20200911170119/http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node128.html